# ListView scrolling behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am making `Listview` with loading of new data when reached the end of the list. When used only mouse wheel it seems to be ok, but when used scrollbar all going wrong. Main idea is to provide effect of continuity list. For this purpose I use `ScrollInToView` in case mouse wheel works fine. But in case scrollbar it dont work. Does anyone know how to fix it?

`Xaml` part:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="SomeContol" >
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Item">
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Height="65" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="64*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="175*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,17,0,18" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Number}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="58" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Shruti" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF9D76FF" Offset="0.163" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#08389FFF" Offset="0.878" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="65*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="246*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="264*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="239*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox 
        SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=SomeContol, Path=SelectedOne}" 
        ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="listBox1_ScrollChanged"
        SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Item}" 
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=SomeContol, Path=SomeColection}" 
        Height="246" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Name="listBox1" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="247" 
        Grid.Row="1" />

</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DateTime DT = DateTime.Now;


    public ObservableCollection<Axle> SomeColection
{
get { return (ObservableCollection<Axle>)GetValue(SomeColectionProperty); }
set { SetValue(SomeColectionProperty, value); }
}

    public Axle SelectedOne
    {
        get { return (Axle)GetValue(SelectedOneProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedOneProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedOne.  This enables        animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedOneProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedOne", typeof(Axle), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));



// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SomeColection.  This enables      animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeColectionProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("SomeColection", typeof(ObservableCollection<Axle>), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public int count = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        SomeColection = new ObservableCollection<Axle>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 30 ; i++)
        {
            count++;
            SomeColection.Add(new Axle(count, count + i));

        }

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void listBox1_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((e.ExtentHeight) == (e.VerticalOffset + e.ViewportHeight)))
        {
            //Go Down


            if (DT < DateTime.Now)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    count++;
                    SomeColection.RemoveAt(0);
                    SomeColection.Add(new Axle(count, count + i));

                }
                SelectedOne = SomeColection[6];
                //SelectedOne = SomeColection[30 -     (int)System.Math.Round(e.ViewportHeight / 65)];
                DT = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1);
            }


        }
        if ((e.VerticalOffset == 0))
        {
            //Go Up
            if (count > 31)
            {

                if(DT<DateTime.Now)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        count--;
                        SomeColection.RemoveAt(29);
                        SomeColection.Insert(0, new Axle(count - 29, i));       
                    }
                    SelectedOne = SomeColection[22];

                    DT = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Selector selector = sender as Selector;
        if (selector is ListBox)
        {
            (selector as ListBox).ScrollIntoView(selector.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ListView supports virtualization.   Why not just load the full SomeCollection?

Comment: because the data is, in principle, be extracted from the database, and more requests will be processed for a long time

Comment: OK from database.  Still why not just get the full List and let virtualization do what it does?

Comment: the problem is that there is no direct access to the database, instead it is implemented by getting single line

Comment: What you're looking for is called "Data virtualization". There's a nice article on this topic that you may find useful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization